# Integer index in SDL_JoystickName in C++

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Look at the simple code below:

```
int main()
{
    int a;
    a = SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_JOYSTICK);
    a = SDL_NumJoysticks();
    for (int i=0; i<a; i++)
        cout << SDL_JoystickName(i);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm using SDL library, It seems there is nothing wrong with the code, I'm trying to get names of connected joysticks but It gives me the error below:

```
error C2664: 'SDL_JoystickName' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'int' to 'SDL_Joystick *'
Conversion from integral type to pointer type requires reinterpret_cast, C-style cast or function-style cast
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: The first problem should be pretty obvious from the error. The second problem is you not reading [the documentation](http://wiki.libsdl.org/FrontPage), where you would have easily found [`SDL_JoystickNameForIndex`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickNameForIndex?highlight=%28\bCategoryAPI\b%29|%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) which *do* take an index, unlike the [`SDL_JoystickName`](http://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickName?highlight=%28\bCategoryAPI\b%29|%28SDLFunctionTemplate%29) which *doesn't*.

Comment: I was reading the wrong documentation: http://www.libsdl.org/release/SDL-1.2.15/docs/html/sdljoystickname.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The documentation states that SDL_JoystickName takes a SDL_Joystick* as parameter (The compiler says the same)
You can retrieve the SDL_Joystick* via SDL_JoystickOpen which takes an int as parameter.

see https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_JoystickName

EDIT: As Joachim Pileborg said, if you just want to retrieve the names, SDL_JoystickNameForIndex is the way to go